# Use command line to add application to gnome classic panel?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gconf, dconf

How can I add an application shortcut to a panel in gnome-classic, using the command line?

I used `dconf watch /` to see what was happening when I did it by hand, but when I try reproducing that myself:

```
dmd@rossum:~ $ dconf write '/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/test1234/object-iid' 'PanelInternalFactory::Launcher'
error: 0-1:unknown keyword
```

I run into trouble right away.

How can I add (e.g.) a terminal launcher icon to a panel using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# add terminal launcher to the bar
dconf load /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/terminal/ << EOT
[instance-config]
location='/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop'

[/]
object-iid='PanelInternalFactory::Launcher'
pack-index=99
pack-type='end'
toplevel-id='top-panel'
EOT
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/object-id-list "$(dconf read /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/object-id-list | sed "s/]/, 'terminal']/")"
```